# Display tags in list without link

Tags: tags, lists

This seems like it should be something that's really simple to do, however it's apparently not.

I don't want tags to be links, but I want them to display in an unordered list, with each tag inside an `<li>`

get_the_tags allows you to echo them without the associated link, but I have no idea how to wrap them in li's.

```
 <?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would do it...

```
 <?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  echo '<ul>';
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo '<li>' .$tag->name. '</li>'; 
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Please explain **why** that could solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks! What are the fullstops on either side of the $tag->name for?

Comment: The periods? In PHP that's the string concatenation operator.

Comment: Hi! I found this is useful. But, when there are more than 1 tag, it shows without a comma. Is there any solution to fix up with a comma when there are more than 1 tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'list_tags' );

function list_tags() {

$tags = get_tags( array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC') );

foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {

echo '<li>' . $tag->name . '</li>';
    }
}
```

Use any WordPress or theme specific hook from your functions file.

Answer (score 0):

This is my preferred solution, to wrap the request with strip_tags to retain formatting options. Here is the code:

```
<?php echo strip_tags ( get_the_tag_list( '<span>', ',&nbsp;', '</span>' ) ); ?>
```

You can also do this for categories.

```
<?php echo strip_tags ( get_the_category_list( '<span>', ',&nbsp;', '</span>' ) ); ?>
```