# How to display tag cloud without links

Tags: tags, cloud

How can a tag cloud generate a list of tags WITHOUT the links? This works fine for me, but I just don't want the links:

```
wp_tag_cloud('smallest=10&largest=10&number=0&format=list');
```

Didn't see anything explicitly in here about this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud

There are similar questions on here, but they have to do with tags for a particular post. I don't want the current page/post tags. I want all tags used on the site in a tag cloud.
[Display tags in list without link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/79967/display-tags-in-list-without-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can modify the output with the filters [`wp_tag_cloud`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L621) or [`wp_generate_tag_cloud`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L802).

But we could also use:

```
echo strip_tags(
    wp_tag_cloud( 'echo=0&smallest=10&largest=10&number=0&format=list' ),
    '<ul><li>'
);
```

where we strip all the HTML tags from the output, except the `ul` and `li` tags.

Notice that we added the `echo=0` parameter as mentioned in the Codex as a way to return the output. We could also have used `echo=` because it has to full fill the [condition](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L631):

```
if ( 'array' == $args['format'] || empty($args['echo']) )
```

to return the output. So `empty( null )` and `empty( '' )` is `true` but it's strange that `empty( 0 )` is also `true`, but that's just how the `empty()` function works ;-)

The [`wp_tag_cloud()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud) function has the `link` parameter, but it only has the possible values as *view* or *edit*. It would be nice to have the *none* option, to disable links and show only the text.

Comment: Great answer. I was thinking about stripping the "href" attribute with Javascript, but I like your server-side solution better. (Also had the same thought about the NONE option.)